# classpath reosource as value spring DSL

Tags: spring, grails, javabeans, dsl

I want to have some alternative to this using Spring DSL in Grails.

```
<bean name="someName" class="SomeClass">
   <property name="resource" value="classpath*:Queues.xml"></property>
</bean>
```

Comment: are you saying you don't want to use resources.groovy?  Can I ask why?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to, you can use resources.xml instead of resources.groovy for a more conventionally Spring-y style.